# Tripartite Matching: Graph Algorithm, Run Time Error

Tags: python, algorithm, search, runtime-error, graph-algorithm

I am practicing problems on Graphs on Hacker Rank. Below is the link for the problem

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/tripartite-matching

I wrote a piece of code and the code seems to run on the test case that is being given. I created some test cases of my own and manually calculated the output and then ran my program and it works. However, for most of the other test cases on Hacker Rank. I get a Run Time Error. I am not sure which Run Time Error it is.

I think my logic is breaking for large input sizes. But I am not sure how.

Below is my code.

```
'''
Input Sequence
3
2
1 2
2 3
3
1 2
1 3
2 3
2
1 3
2 3

'''
#Stores the data of the graph
class Graph:


    def __init__(self,parent_node,child_node):
        self.node_map = {}
        self.node_map[parent_node] = [child_node]
        self.node_map[child_node] = [parent_node]

    def getNodeMap(self):
        return self.node_map

    def deleteKey(self, parent_node):
        del self.node_map[parent_node]

    def printGraph(self):
        print self.node_map

    def getChildren(self, parent_node):
        return self.node_map[parent_node]

    def getAllParents(self):
        return self.node_map.keys()

    def add(self,parent_node,child_node):
        #Adding the Node and Edge Details
        # Adding Parent and Child
        if (parent_node in self.node_map):
            child_list = []
            child_list = self.node_map[parent_node]
            child_list.append(child_node)
            self.node_map[parent_node] = child_list
        else:
            self.node_map[parent_node] = [child_node]

        if (child_node in self.node_map):
            parent_list = self.node_map[child_node]
            parent_list.append(parent_node)
            self.node_map[child_node] = parent_list
        else:
            self.node_map[child_node] = [parent_node]



def runDFS(parent,seq,graph_num):
    #print seq
    if(graph_num == len(all_graphs)):
        all_sequences.append(seq)
        return
    else:
        if(parent not in all_graphs[graph_num].getAllParents()):
            return
        children = all_graphs[graph_num].getChildren(parent)
        for child in children:
                new_set = copy.deepcopy(s)
                new_seq = copy.deepcopy(seq)
                new_seq.append(child)
                runDFS(child,new_seq,graph_num+1)








import sys
import fileinput
import copy
import sys

all_graphs = []
all_sequences = []
list_sequences = []


graphs = raw_input()
#print 'Graphs are', graphs
g = [Graph for i in range(int(graphs))]
for i in range(0,int(graphs)):
    g[i] = Graph(-999*i,-999*i)
    #print 'Read no. of Edges'
    edges = raw_input()
    #print edges
    for j in range(0,int(edges)):
        #print 'Read Edge Info'
        edge_info = raw_input()
        parent_node = edge_info[0]
        child_node = edge_info[2]
        g[i].add(parent_node, child_node)
    g[i].deleteKey(-999*i)
    all_graphs.append(g[i])


#for i in range(0,len(all_graphs)):
#    print all_graphs[i].getNodeMap()


graph_num = 0
all_sequences = []


sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)


for item in all_graphs[graph_num].getAllParents():
    s = set()
    s.add(item)
    seq = list()
    seq.append(item)
    runDFS(item,seq,graph_num)


#print all_sequences
counter = 0

for item in all_sequences:
    #print item
    end_node = item[len(item)-1]
    start_node = item[0]
    if(end_node == start_node):
        counter = counter + 1


print counter
```

Would really appreciate some help. Is there a bug in my logic or is my assumption right?

If the code is not working for larger input sizes than what is the best way to optimize it?

Instead of running DFS, I used the following approach. But the same thing happens here as well. I think there is some problem with my IO. I am not able to figure out what... :(

```
for itemA in all_graphs[0].getAllParents():
    for itemB in all_graphs[0].getChildren(itemA):
        for itemC in all_graphs[1].getChildren(itemB):
            if(itemA in all_graphs[2].getChildren(itemC)):
                counter = counter + 1
print counter
```

Comment: @greybeard , I get the Run Time Error. I corrected the title.

Comment: Please _quote_: cut&paste any error messages. I take that you `I get a Run Time Error.` from hackerrank.com - what happens if you feed your code large input in your test environment?

Comment: @greybeard .. Nothing happens, it shows no result. It looks as if it is waiting for more input.

Comment: Try to find an input (size) that takes on the order of one second. Increase input size _slowly_: how does the run time vary? From eye-balling your code, I'd guess O(n³) - that may prove prohibitive for input sizes of interest (-> you'd need a better problem analysis/algorithm). Put in "heartbeat-output-statements" - print something that gets flushed every legion of (most) simple units of work.